error building a react native android app
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Settings file 'D:\flightplanner\android\settings.gradle' line: 13

What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react.settings'] was not found in any of the following sources:



Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
Included Builds (No included builds contain this plugin)
Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)

i tried using expo to automate the building process but always comes with this error

Welcome to StackOverflow. Providing accurate error content can help you get answers :)

This question is similar to: Error Plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react.settings'] was not found in any of the following sources:, when upgrading to "react-native": "0.75.1". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
